# access FormControl in FormGroup inside FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, form-control

I am trying to implement material autocorrect on formcontrol within formarray but when I am trying to access formcontrol in ts file, it is failing to access it. Can anyone please help me.

html file:

```
<div formArrayName="applicants">
          <div *ngFor="let applicant of appForm.controls.applicants.controls; let i=index; let last = last">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="row">
                <label for="applicant_short_name" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Applicant {{i+1}}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- <input type="text" formControlName="applicant_short_name" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Applicant"> -->
                    <!-- <mat-form-field > -->
                      <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Applicant" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControlName]="applicant_short_name">
                      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredNames | async | slice:0:3" [value]="name">
                          <span>{{ name }}</span>
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-autocomplete>
                    <!-- </mat-form-field> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
```

ts file:

```
    this.appForm.controls.applicants.controls[0].controls.applicant_short_name.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.filterNames(val);
 });
```

where appform is my formgroup
applicants is formarray
applicants short name is formcontrol.

as of now controls[0] is throwing error that controls does not exists on AbstractControl.

Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting this error on console"?

Comment: I am unable to compile itself. This error is from compilation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your object types as concrete classes instead of relying on the interface only. I am assuming that `appForm` is defined as a `FormGroup` or `FormArray` somewhere in your code (you should show all relevant code). But the `controls` member of both classes returns `AbstractControl[]` and the `AbstractControl` interface has no `controls` member - it is defined only at the class level in `FormGroup` and `FormArray`. So, assuming you are using `FormGroup`s, you need to cast:

```
const outerGroup: FormGroup = this.appForm.controls.applicants as FormGroup;
const innerGroup: FormGroup = outerGroup.controls[0] as FormGroup;
innerGroup.controls.applicant_short_name.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.filterNames(val);
});
```

You could also just cast the statement inline but that would get very messy to read.